# Printing the index of an item in the item

Tags: c#, list, indexof

I'm trying to get the index of an item in a list to appear in the item when it's printed, so something like

```
List<string> listy = new List<string>();
listy.Add("Index of this item is: " + index);
```

I want the index to be an object that can be passed as an argument in a method.

Comment: No idea what you are asking... Can you show maybe desired result ?

Comment: Maybe you are asking for `listy.Add($"Some thext {listy.Count}")`? Also when [edit] post clarify how it should behave when you insert items in the middle of the list.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: There are many different ways something like this can be achieved. However, it is hard to tell what is right for you. Could you provide some more context about the code you are working with and the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: you need to edit to make the problem clearly  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> listy = new List<string>();
listy.Add("Index of this item is: " + list.Count);
```

Should work in this particular case because Add adds an item to the end of the list which the index of the new last item will be equal to the old count.

Answer (score 0):

Concating the "index" to the value of an item you are adding to a `List` at the time the item is added is not a good idea. The actual `index` of the entry in a `List` **can** change throughout the lifetime of the `List` due to operations such as `RemoveAt`, `Insert`, `Sort` and `Reverse` just to name a few. Just for this reason alone one should evaluate the `index` at the time it is needed.

The OP problem statement is to "Print the Index". I will take that literally. So lets print(!) the index with the item.
Just use:

```
myList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x}:{lx.IndexOf(x)}"));
```

Let us see how this would work in example code:

```
    private static void PrintWithIndexBetterIdea()
    {
        var lx = new List<string>();
        lx.Add("A ");
        lx.Add("B ");
        lx.Add("C ");
        lx.Insert(2, "D ");
        lx.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Item {x} real index: {lx.IndexOf(x)}"));
    }
```

Here is why concating the index with the item you are entering is not such a good idea. There is a method belonging to the `List` called `Insert`. You can insert a new item in the list which makes the "hard coded" variation useless. To demonstrate:

```
    private static void PrintWithIndexBadIdea()
    {
        var lx = new List<string>();
        lx.Add("A " + lx.Count);
        lx.Add("B " + lx.Count);
        lx.Add("C " + lx.Count);
        lx.Insert(2, "D 2");
        lx.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        lx.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"Item{x} real index: {lx.IndexOf(x)}"));
    }
```

Results:

```
From PrintWithIndexBadIdea:
A 0
B 1
D 2
C 2
ItemA 0 real index: 0
ItemB 1 real index: 1
ItemD 2 real index: 2
ItemC 2 real index: 3

From PrintWithIndexBetterIdea 
Item A  real index: 0
Item B  real index: 1
Item D  real index: 2
Item C  real index: 3
```